# What's happen that _id attribute in FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

I was surprised by this behavior.

Perhaps.
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/8a65569f102ac2593e7c73bd029d5072e4641af8/lib/factory_girl/aliases.rb
is may be affects. but I have no idea.

why missing `values( @rank )` in factory girl?

### sample

```
require 'factory_girl'
class Book
  attr_accessor :rank, :rank_id
end
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :book do
    rank 3
  end
end
puts FactoryGirl.build(:book).inspect
    #=> #<Book:0x007fb748207770 @rank=3>
puts FactoryGirl.build(:book, rank_id: 10).inspect
    #=> #<Book:0x007fb7481dd6a0 @rank_id=10> (missing @rank)
puts FactoryGirl.build(:book, rank: 1).inspect
    #=> #<Book:0x007fb7481ef6e8 @rank=1>
puts FactoryGirl.build(:book, rank: 2, rank_id: 10).inspect
    #=> #<Book:0x007fb7481d60f8 @rank_id=10> (missing @rank)
```

Comment: Actually. It found when make rspec to processing common with alias_attribute as like as polymorphically _id reference on rails. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be important for `ActiveRecord`.

If you don't want that behavior you might do some monkey patching:

```
module FactoryGirl
  self.aliases = []
end
```

Comment: Yes, Its works. I will be tinkering to no side-effect. Thank you.